# AngularJS - Why does a promise trigger a controller reload?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a question regarding AngularJS; it is behavior I do not understand - that is, I had expected one thing, but got something completely different. Now the unexpected behavior may be right in its own right but I would like to understand why it happens.

Given this very crude code (and this is actual code acting as a POC):

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('Promises', function ($q) {
    return {
      promises: function (val) {
        var d = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function() {
          d.resolve(val);
        }, 1000);

        return d.promise;
      }
    };
  });

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function (Promises) {
    console.log("Reload!");
    this.messages = this.messages || [ "hello" ];

    var that = this;
    this.scrappy = function() {
      console.log("Before: ", that.messages);

      Promises.promises(12).then(function(promise) {
        console.log("Fetching a promise", promise);
        that.messages.push("" + promise.toString());
        console.log("During: ", that.messages);
      }).finally(
        function(x) { console.log("Finaly: ", that.messages); }
      );
    };
  });
```

So far so good; I have a scrappy function, and when I `ng-click` some button, the scrappy function is called which fires a promise and after a second the list receives a push with the inserted value.

Right? At least; that was my presumption...

Turns out something else happens and I cannot figure out why, or what the reasoning behind it is.

When I launch my app in the browser and click the button twice; this is what the console.log tells me:

```
# first hit
Reload! main.js:12
# now I click the button
Before:  ["hello"] main.js:17
Reload! main.js:12
Fetching a promise 12 main.js:20
During:  ["hello", "12"] main.js:22
Finaly:  ["hello", "12"] main.js:25
# now I click the button again
Before:  ["hello"] main.js:17
Reload! main.js:12
Fetching a promise 12 main.js:20
During:  ["hello", "12"] main.js:22
Finaly:  ["hello", "12"] main.js:25
```

The big question here is:

1. Why is the controller function being re-executed during promise resolve?
2. And how can I stop that from happening?

[edit]

Per request; the HTML (as-is):

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-controller='MainCtrl as main'>
  <h1>'Allo, 'Allo!</h1>
  <p class="lead">
    <img src="images/yeoman.png" alt="I'm Yeoman"><br>
    Always a pleasure scaffolding your apps.
  </p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-href="#" ng-click="main.scrappy()">Splendid!<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a></p>
</div>
```

BTW: This is yeoman generated, using a `routeProvider`

[/edit]

Comment: can you show the html??

Comment: Can you post the template where MainCtrl is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `ng-controller='MainCtrl'` in an `ng-repeat` or `ng-include` somewhere inside your html

Comment: afaics that is not the case; I do have an `ng-controller='MainCtrl as main'` but even when I alter the `routeProvider` and the template, the problem remains (or is the `routeProvider` my culprit?)

Comment: After some more research, turns out `routeProvider` is my culprit, or at least, `ng-view` (as provided by) is.